# How to insert an item in a Selectable control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable

Is there a "clean" way to insert an item in a jQuery UI Selectable control?

Say, I have the following Selectable:

```
<div id="selectable">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

I could manually insert a row like:

```
$('<div>Item 4</div>').addClass('ui-selectee').appendTo($('#selectable'));
```

While it visually looks correct, is there any events I need to include as well? Is that a clean way to insert an item, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no api for doing it. So I believe your coding is a correct way. You may also try to call the `.selectable( "refresh")` after addition.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-autoRefresh) you can also just use the option *autoRefresh* (enabled by default) to extend the list of selectable-elements as you add elements to the DOM-element.

If you have a huge list of elements it's recommended to set *autoRefresh* to false and call the method *refresh* manually.